# How to set new column based on multiple conditions in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to collect catalogue information based on text search. Search for a certain string in column `Text`, and put some description into a new column `C_Organization`.

Here is the sample data:

```
# load packages:
pacman::p_load("data.table",
               "stringr")

# make sample data:
DE <- data.table(c("John", "Sussan", "Bill"),
                 c("Text contains MIT", "some text with Stanford University", "He graduated from Yale"))

colnames(DE) <- c("Name", "Text")

> DE
     Name                               Text
1:   John                  Text contains MIT
2: Sussan some text with Stanford University
3:   Bill             He graduated from Yale
```

search for a certain string and make a new data.table with new column:

```
mit <- DE[str_detect(DE$Text, "MIT"), .(Name, C_Organization = "MIT")]
yale <- DE[str_detect(DE$Text, "Yale"), .(Name, C_Organization = "Yale")]
stanford <- DE[str_detect(DE$Text, "Stanford"), .(Name, C_Organization = "Stanford")]

# bind them together:
combine_table <- rbind(mit, yale, stanford)

combine_table

     Name C_Organization
1:   John            MIT
2:   Bill           Yale
3: Sussan       Stanford
```

This *pick-and-combine* approach works fine but it seems a little bit tedious. Is it possible to do it in one step in `data.table`?

**Edit**

Due to my poor data analysis skill and the unclean data, I need to make the question clear:

1. The real data is a little complicated:

   (1) There are cases where a person from more than two organizations, like `Jack, UC Berkeley, Bell lab`. and

   (2) The same person of the same organization appears for different year, like `Steven, MIT, 2011`, `Steven, MIT, 2014`.
2. I want to figure out:

   (1) How many people from each organization. If one person belongs to more than one organization, make the organization which appears most as his organization. (i.e. by popularity.) For example, `John, MIT, AMS, Bell lab`, if `MIT` appears 30 times, `AMS` 12 times, `Bell lab` 26 times. Then make `MIT` as his organization.

   (2) count how many people for each year. This is not directly realted to my original question, but for later calculation, I don't want to throw away these records.

Comment: you mean you have the vector `v = c("MIT","Yale","Stanford")` and you want to retrieve all rows in `DE` having this in column `text` ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for asking. You expressed my question in a much better way. I should have mentioned that this vector might be longer in the real data set.

Comment: Your `pacman::` call reduces reproducibility of the question. You could use `sapply(c("pkg1","pkg2"), require)`

Comment: @jangorecki Thank you for letting me know this. I was allways trying to find out how to write `require(pkg1), require(pkg2)...` concisely. `sapply` is really a good idea, for it doesn't require an extra package like `pacman`.

Comment: @Nick, in case there is several same school per Name, does the display below satisfies you?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thank you very much for your answer. I'm trying to understand your answer and Jaap's answer. The real data is a little complicated - (1) There are cases where a person from more than two organizations, like `Jack, UC Berkeley, Bell lab`. and (2) The same person, the same organization appears for different year, like `Steven, MIT, 2011`, `Steven, MIT, 2014`.

Comment: @ what do you want as output in these cases?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I want to figure out: (1) How many people from each organization. If one person belongs to more than one organization, make the organization which appears most as his organization. (i.e. by popularity.) For example, `John, MIT, AMS, Bell lab`, if MIT appears 30 times, AMS 12 times, Bell lab 26 times. Then make MIT as his organization. (2) count how many people for each year. This is not directly realted to my original question, but for later calculation, I don't want to throw away these records.

Comment: You should reformulate your question because this one is not clear enough... what happens also in case of equality? I guess the answer below do not reflect what you want. I will certainly delete mine.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I'll edit my question right now. This delima is caused by my poor data analysis skill and the unclean data. Thank you for your answer - you've alread teach me something.

Comment: @Nick I will look at this, you can suppress 'poor data and analysis' comment since you make effort to express it in a clear way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution which takes into account for several matches in one text, operates rowwise and binds the matches together:

```
uni <- c("MIT","Yale","Stanford")
DE[,idx:=.I][, c_org := paste(uni[str_detect(Text, uni)], collapse=","), idx]
```

this gives:

```
> DE
     Name                                   Text idx             c_org
1:   John                      Text contains MIT   1               MIT
2: Sussan     some text with Stanford University   2          Stanford
3:   Bill He graduated from Yale, MIT, Stanford.   3 MIT,Yale,Stanford
4:   Bill                              some text   4
```

The advantage of operating rowwise is evident when you have identical names in `Name`. When you do:

```
DE[, uni[str_detect(Text, uni)], Name]
```

you get not the correct result:

```
     Name       V1
1:   John      MIT
2: Sussan Stanford
3:   Bill      MIT
4:   Bill Stanford
```

=> you don't know which Bill you have in the fourth row. Moreover, `Yale` isn't included for the 'first' Bill (i.e. row 3 of the original dataset).

---

Used data:

```
DE <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "Sussan", "Bill", "Bill"), Text = c("Text contains MIT", "some text with Stanford University", "He graduated from Yale, MIT, Stanford.", "some text")), .Names = c("Name", "Text"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how does `uni[str_detect(Text, uni)]` work?

Comment: @Nick It returns the value from the `uni` vector for which there is a match in the `Text` column.

Comment: So `uni[True, False, True]` returns `MIT, Stanford`?  How can a vector accept a boolean value and returns its elements?

Comment: @Nick You have to use `uni[c(T, F, T)]` to get those values. By adding `[c(T, F, T)]` to `uni`, you give `uni` an index which values should be kep. In this case the first and the last one.