# How to pick the first comma separated value in a column in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Courtesy of @Jaap's answer from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647943/how-to-set-new-column-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-data-table/32649235?noredirect=1#comment53153560_32649235)

The data is something like this:

```
Name                                   Text idx             c_org
1:   John                      Text contains MIT   1               MIT
2: Sussan     some text with Stanford University   2          Stanford
3:   Bill He graduated from Yale, MIT, Stanford.   3 MIT,Yale,Stanford
4:   Bill                              some text   4
```

For the column `c_org`, if there's multiple values, as in observation 3, `MIT,Yale,Stanford`, I'd make the first value, `MIT` as the column value. The result should like this:

```
Name                                   Text idx             NewOrg
1:   John                      Text contains MIT   1               MIT
2: Sussan     some text with Stanford University   2          Stanford
3:   Bill He graduated from Yale, MIT, Stanford.   3               MIT
4:   Bill                              some text   4
```

(please note that in the `c_org` column, some field has more than one value, some even is empty. In the expected output, if there's only one value, keep it; if more than one, keep the first one; if empty, keep empty.)

I tried this (but failed):

```
DT[ , str_split(c_org, ",")[[1]][1]]
```

I guess it is quite common to met data that there are more than one value in one field. How to do it in `data.table`? (Or in other way if the solution is better than `data.table`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the pattern `,` followed by one or more characters (`.*`) until the end (`$`) of the string  in the 'c_org' column and replace it with `''`.  The output can be assigned (`:=`) to create the column 'NewOrg', and assign the 'c_org' to NULL.

```
DT[, NewOrg := sub(',.*$', '', c_org)][,c_org:= NULL]
DT
#     Name                                   Text idx   NewOrg
#1:   John                      Text contains MIT   1      MIT
#2: Sussan     some text with Stanford University   2 Stanford
#3:   Bill He graduated from Yale, MIT, Stanford.   3      MIT
#4:   Bill                              some text   4
```

Or another option from data.table `v1.9.6+` is `tstrsplit`

```
DT[, NewOrg := tstrsplit(c_org, ',', fill='')[[1]]][, c_org:= NULL]
```